# Не отгружается заказ в Мой склад выдает 413 ошибку

Tags: мойсклад-api, moysklad-json-api

Вопрос по [МойСкладAPI](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#header-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Вот мы столкнулись сегодня с крупным заказом - клиент реально оформил заказ на более 100 товарных позиций

Он не выгрузился из-за ошибки

**Ошибка подключения: 413; Ошибка формата: слишком большое число вложенных объектов;**

Отсюда вопрос именно как обрабатывать и выгружать подобного рода крупные заказы?

Answer (score -1):

Для работы с позициями заказов в remap 1.1 используйте [api работы с позициями](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/#header-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2). Примеры работы приведены [тут](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/#%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F).